# Why is Kafka broker lag so high after a brief period of "silence" in message production?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I've spent hours trying to optimize my kafka broker for latency with no luck. The problem I am experiencing is that initial messages produced to a topic after a brief period (5-10 seconds or cold start) of "silence" take roughly 3-4 seconds to show up in the topic and be ready for consumer consumption. The latency between the messages once messages start to appear in the topic is very good (<1ms) but the initial latency before messages start to appear in the topic is very high. I am developing an application with very low latency requirements so this is isn't acceptable to me so I am hoping that there is a setting either in the broker or consumer that I can change to get rid of this high initial latency.

Problem was initially noticed during the database insertion due to having fields that keep track of when message was created and inserted into db. However, I do not think the issue is the database since looking in Confluent Control Center I see the same latency in messages in the topic and roughly 6-7ms is due to data insertion into the database.

Here are my settings:

**Cluster:**

1 broker, 2 partitions per topic, 8 core 2.8ghz cpu (development)

**Parameters I've tried changing in Kafka Broker:**

- log.flush.interval.messages
- log.flush.interval.ms
- log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms

**Parameters I've tried changing in Kafka JDBC Connector:**

- heartbeat.interval.ms

P.S I'm using rust but should be easy to read the configs

**Producer settings:**

```
let producer: FutureProducer = ClientConfig::new()
    .set("bootstrap.servers", kafka_broker_address.clone())
    .set("batch.size", "1")
    .set("acks","all")
    .set("linger.ms","0")
    .set("compression.type", "lz4")
    .set("enable.idempotence", "true")
    .create()
    .expect("error");
```

**Kafka broker settings (in docker file):**

```
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.0.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 2
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
```

**Kafka Connect JDBC Sink Connector:**

```
curl -i -X PUT http://$KAFKA_CONNECT_SERVER_ADDRESS:$KAFKA_CONNECT_SERVER_PORT/connectors/db1-sink-postgres-topic_a/config \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{
            "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
            "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
            "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
            "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://'$DB_SERVER_ADDRESS_FROM_INSIDE_DOCKER_CONTAINER':'$DB_SERVER_PORT'/'$DB_NAME'",
            "connection.user": "'$DB_USER'",
            "connection.password": "'$DB_USER_PWD'",
            "consumer.override.isolation.level": "read_committed",
            "insert.mode": "upsert",
            "pk.mode": "record_value",
            "pk.fields": "id, year",
            "topics": "topic_a",
            "errors.log.enable":true,
            "errors.log.include.messages":true,
            "transforms": "TimestampConverter",
            "transforms.TimestampConverter.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
            "transforms.TimestampConverter.format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z",
            "transforms.TimestampConverter.field":"program_datetime_eastern_when_retrieved",
            "transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type":"Timestamp"
         }'
```

Comment: Have you tried manually flushing the producer after sending? And if you want low latency to a database, don't use JDBC sink which uses batching

Answer (score 0):

Issue was unrelated to Kafka, I was comparing incorrect timestamp values that also accounted for processing time of said messages before being produced to topic.